# accepting click events in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, events, onclick, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a few `TextView` as children

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/shift_parent_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shift_parent_nametitle"
        android:text="@string/shift_parent_nametitle"
        style="@style/header_text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shift_parent_namefield"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/shift_parent_nametitle"
        style="@style/wrap"
        />
```

How do I go about using the `RelativeLayout` as a *button* to react to a *click event* if any part of the area is pressed?

Comment: If setting the RelativeLayout to clickable and focusable doesn't help, it may be because of neighbouring views. Try `shift_parent_name.bringToFront()`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just add a [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) to your RelativeLayout

Answer (score 22):

I have a RelativeLayout called "RelativeMain1". This is how i make it start Activity

```
RelativeLayout relativeclic1 =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeMain1);
         relativeclic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                 startActivityForResult(new Intent(A_My_Galaxy.this,C_Student_Book_Planet.class), 0);
             }
         });
```

After you add the onClickListener to your layout, it should work.

Answer (score 7):

Add a "OnClickListener" to your RelativeLayout.

**Note:** Don't forget to add `android:clickable="true"` to your RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 7):

1. Give your `RelativeLayout` an ID, like you typed `shift_parent_name`
2. Set your `RelativeLayout` XML to `android:clickable="true"`

   Your final xml will be look like this:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/shift_parent_name"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="0.25"
   android:clickable="true">
   ```
3. then add the code in your onCreate method :

   ```
   RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.shift_parent_name);
     relative1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
           startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, About.class) );
       }
   });
   ```

Make sure to change your activity names, `Main.this` and `About.class`.

The main activity called `Main.java` and the second is `About.java`

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeMain1);
         relativeclic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){

             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just add this `android:onClick="onClick"`

Comment: Not to layouts (at least in my case straight onClick that worked on `ImageView`  needed replacement by `OnClickListener`).